# Uniqueness of change of basis matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have matrices $A$ and $B$ that are equivalent, that is:

$$A = QBP^{-1}$$

for some invertible matrices $Q$ and $P$.

Is there only one (unique) choice of $P$ and $Q$ for particular $A$ and $B$?

Comment: $A=PBP^{-1}$ see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity for details.

Answer (score 3):

The equation holds if $Q$ is replaced by $2Q$ and $P$ by $2P$.